# Integration test for single Spring Boot @Service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm writing an integration test for this Spring Boot `@Service` bean

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.thymeleaf.ITemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class ThymeLeafEmailTemplateService implements EmailTemplateService {

    private final ITemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

    public ThymeLeafEmailTemplateService(ITemplateEngine springTemplateEngine) {
        this.springTemplateEngine = springTemplateEngine;
    }

    public String generateEmailBody(String template, Map<String, Object> variables) {
        Context context = new Context(Locale.getDefault(), variables);
        return springTemplateEngine.process(template, context);
    }
}
```

Currently, the test class is defined as shown below

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ThymeLeafEmailTemplateServiceTests {


    @Autowired
    private EmailTemplateService service;

    @Test
    void generateTaskNotificationEmail() {
      var output = service.generateEmailBody("/template", Map.of());
      assertEquals("Expected Output", output);
    }
}
```

A problem with this approach is that it's very slow/inefficient because the entire application context is loaded, but I really only need the service being tested and its dependencies.

If I change the test class' annotations to

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ThymeLeafEmailTemplateService.class)
```

the test fails, because the dependency `ITemplateEngine springTemplateEngine` does not exist. I could add this dependency to `classes` (the list of beans to create), but this seems like a very brittle approach.

Is there an efficient way to integration test a single `@Service`?

### Note:

I know I could mock `ITemplateEngine springTemplateEngine` and write a unit test instead, but I want to test the template's actual output, so this approach won't work

Comment: Load your service and the thymeleaf configuration. You could even do this manually without Spring (Boot) .

Comment: @M.Deinum could you post an answer with more details?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
@WebMvcTest(ThymeLeafEmailTemplateService.class)
```

This will load only that bean in your application context along with any default Spring configuration beans.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "default Spring configuration beans", but I tried this and it didn't work because the dependency could not be satisfied

Comment: Sorry, i think @WebMvcTest(ThymeLeafEmailTemplateService.class) should work. I tested it. @SpringBootTest annotation does not instantiate the necessary web mvc beans such as the template engine. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact requirement and solved it with the following config.

In my test case just call the components that are needed for the execution of the process, in this case, my service (CreaFormatoContrareciboServiceImpl) and the repository inside the service (ContrareciboRepository) and also a customized configuration for the database (RepositoryConfiguration) this is because the configuratión generated by jhipster it is not working correctly.
found this here [https://tanzu.vmware.com/](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/spring-boot-testing/#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20microservices%20can%20be,scenario%20in%20the%20annotation%20declaration.)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ContrareciboRepository.class, CreaFormatoContrareciboServiceImpl.class, RepositoryConfiguration.class})
 class CreaFormatoContrareciboServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private CreaFormatoContrareciboService creaFormatoContrareciboService;
    
    @Test
    void whenCodeIsFound() throws JRException {
        String codigo = "DEMO";
        
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = this.creaFormatoContrareciboService.obtener(codigo);
        
        assertNotNull(jasperPrint);
        
    }
}
```